# У меня есть ListBox в котором есть checkBox'ы ,как при нажатии на один из них cделать выбранным элемент списка, в котором он находится?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Вот код моего listBox`a ,как можно при клике на checkBox(isChecked==true,Name =SelectMessage),чтобы данный элемент был выбран в списке и нельзя было выбирать несколько элементов  при помощи CTRL.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxOfMessages"  SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="0,0,15,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate > 
                <DataTemplate  >
                    <Grid Name="Grid2"  > 
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition  />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel Name="MyStack" Grid.Column="0"  >
                            <CheckBox Margin="2" Name="SelectMessage" Click="SelectMessage_Click" />
                            <CheckBox Name="CircleCheckBox" Click="CircleCheckBox_Click" Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBoxCircle}"/>
                            <CheckBox Name="FlagCheckBox" Click="FlagCheckBox_Click"  Style="{StaticResource styleCustomCheckBoxFlag}"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"  >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}"  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime}" FontSize="11"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: А что должно произойти с чекбоксом, когда будет выбран другой элемент списка?

Comment: @VladD Остаться в прежнем состоянии,до тек пор ,пока пользователь не нажмет на него.

Comment: Хорошо, а если он нажат, и юзер снова нажимает на него, что должно случиться с выбранным элементом списка?

Comment: @VladD Стать не выбранным элементом в списке.

Comment: А какой элемент должен стать при этом выбранным? Никакой?

Comment: @Vlad У каждого элемента списка есть свой checkbox,и необходимо сделать так,чтобы тот элемент у которого был выбран checkBox становился выбранным,или наобарот не выбранным в зависимости от состояния до нажатия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам хочется немного нестандартного поведения. У вас выбор выделенного объекта не привязан строго к состоянию данных. В принципе, никакой проблемы в этом нет, но придётся немного использовать code-behind.

Пишем:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxOfMessages" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="SelectMessage" Click="SelectMessage_Click" Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Я немного упростил ваш XAML для примера. Также добавил `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`, чтобы растянуть контент на вся ширину элемента.

Теперь, code-behind.

```
private void SelectMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    var container = FindParentOfType<ListBoxItem>(checkBox);
    container.IsSelected = checkBox.IsChecked.Value;
}

static private T FindParentOfType<T>(FrameworkElement element) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    while (element != null)
    {
        if (element is T t)
            return t;
        element = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Запускаем, получается вот что:

[image: Вдруг охотник выбегает, и в бан Кролика на 416 дней!]

Comment: Ругается на конструкцию if(element is T t) return t;Как правильно ее преобразовать?

Comment: @Nikita: У вас старая Студия?

Comment: 2015 года ,это сильно влияет?

Comment: Я решил эту проблему,спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Nikita: Да, старая версия языка не поддерживает эту конструкцию. Вам нужно что-то такое: `T t = element as T; if (t != null) return t;`

Comment: я так и сделал)

Comment: @Nikita: Ну вот и хорошо, что разобрались!

Comment: @VladD, а может стоило переопределить `ItemContainerStyle` и туда запихнуть `CheckBox` с простейшим `Binding`?

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov: Я сначала так и хотел, но автору нужно нестандартное поведение: выделенный элемент должен быть только один, а вот CheckBox'ов много. Если бы сделать очевидным образом с привязкой, то были бы одновременно выделены все элементы с отмеченными CheckBox'ами

Comment: @VladD, а действительно, ну в таком случае или Ваш способ, или аж через новое кастомное свойство для `ListBoxItem`.